# How to generate array of unique number in VB.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, random, synchronization

I need to implement a function that generates arrays of an unique combination number?
This function will be accessible by a lot of devices (by using threads), and each device should get an unique address id (array of sbyte).

I previously used a function in C# to generate an unique number but I don't know how to implement this new case in VB.net.

```
public class GetUniqueNumber
{
    static private  int id = 0;
    static private final Object lock = new Object();


    public int getId()
    {
        synchronized (lock)
       {
            int temp = id;
            id++;
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `SyncLock`, like this:

```
Public Class GetUniqueNumber
    Private Shared id As Integer = 0
    Private Shared lock = New Object()

    Public Function getId() As Integer
        SyncLock lock
            Dim temp As Integer = id
            id += 1
            Return temp
        End SyncLock
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

As integer

```
Public Class GetUniqueNumber
    Private Shared id As Integer = 0
    Private Shared lock As New Object
    Public ReadOnly Property getID() As Integer
        Get
            Dim temp As Integer
            SyncLock lock
                temp = id
                id += 1
            End SyncLock
            Return temp
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

as byte array

```
Public Class GetUniqueNumber
    Private Shared id As Integer = 0
    Private Shared lock As New Object

    Public ReadOnly Property getID() As Byte()
        Get
            Dim temp As Byte()
            SyncLock lock
                temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(id)
                id += 1
            End SyncLock
            Return temp
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

as byte array from int16

```
Public Class GetUniqueNumber
    Private Shared id As Int16 = 0
    Private Shared lock As New Object

    Public ReadOnly Property getID() As Byte()
        Get
            Dim temp As Byte()
            SyncLock lock
                temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(id)
                id += 1S
            End SyncLock
            Return temp
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

using biginteger

```
Public Class GetUniqueNumber
    Private Shared id As BigInteger = 0
    Private Shared lock As New Object

    Public ReadOnly Property getID() As Byte()
        Get
            Dim temp As Byte()
            SyncLock lock
                temp = id.ToByteArray
                id += 1
            End SyncLock
            If temp.Length <> 16 Then
                Array.Resize(temp, 16)
            End If
            Return temp
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

or

```
Public Class GetUniqueNumber
    Private Shared idLS As Long = 0L
    Private Shared idMS As Long = 0L
    Private Shared lock As New Object

    Public ReadOnly Property getID() As Byte()
        Get
            Dim tempLS() As Byte
            Dim tempMS() As Byte
            Dim rv(15) As Byte
            SyncLock lock
                tempLS = BitConverter.GetBytes(idLS)
                tempMS = BitConverter.GetBytes(idMS)
                If idLS = Long.MaxValue Then
                    idMS += 1L
                    idLS = 0L
                Else
                    idLS += 1L
                End If
                Array.Reverse(tempLS)
                Array.Reverse(tempMS)
                Array.Copy(tempLS, 0, rv, 8, tempLS.Length)
                Array.Copy(tempMS, 0, rv, 0, tempMS.Length)
            End SyncLock
            Return rv
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to indicate that the array must have a fix length (16).

Comment: Sorry but when I perform test, the length of "temp" array returned is 2.
That expected is something like: 
    Dim temp() as Byte = New Byte() {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}.
Maybe I was not very clear

Comment: maybe "Redim Preserve temp(15)" should be resolve the problem

Comment: I'm working on the Framework 2.0 so I don't have BigInteger type.

Comment: See last edit.  Can't imagine ever needing a number this large.

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
' Define other methods and classes here
public class GetUniqueNumber
    shared id as integer=0
    shared readonly lock =new Object()
    public function getId() as integer

        SyncLock lock
            dim temp =id
            id=id+1
            return temp
        end synclock
    end function
    end class
```

Comment: yes this code is similar as the C# code that I have posted, but now I need to generate an array[16] of unique combination numbers,not only an int value.